# How to change selectbox into textbox in symfony 1.2 framework?

Tags: php, symfony-1.2

I am new to the symfony framework. I've worked on an already existing project so I want change
a selectbox into a textbox using symfony 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information and code snippets would have helped but..

There are several places this could be achieved, I will go for the 2 most direct and hopefully, common.

1)
Your form has already been customised and will likely live in `plugins/yourPlugin/lib/form/yourForm.class.php`

In here there will be something like `$this->setWidget('my_input', new sfWidgetChoice(array([...])));`

There are many "Choice" widgets it may be (Doctrine or Propel if they come from the database)

You will need to change it to `$this->setWidget('my_input', new sfWidgetFormInput());`

2) 
Your form has not been modified before and is the generated form

You will need to go into your `actions.class.php` (or `components.class.php`) and find where it says `$this->form = new yourForm();`

Make a new form in `plugins/yourPlugin/lib/form` and make it extend your previous form.

```
class yourNewForm extends yourForm
```

Then add

```
public function setup()
{
 $this->setWidget('my_input', new sfWidgetFormInput());
}
```

You will likely have to update the validator as well, or it will be expecting data in the "selct box" format.

http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_1/sfWidgetFormInput